# What is the maximum xeon fpu precision?

Tags: floating-point, x86-64, floating-point-precision

"I think i know" that all X86/X64 processors floating point units have a width of 80 Bits, but i don't find any substantial documentation about that.

Any References?

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct floating-point units on a modern x86 processor ("xeon" is a marketing name, and has no relation to any of this):

- x87, which provides operations on an 80-bit double-extended data type, but can be configured (via a control register setting) to round to single- or double-precision instead (though such settings do not effect the exponent range of intermediate calculations, which sometimes causes surprising results).
- The more modern SSE (and SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, ...), which provide scalar and vector operations on IEEE-754 single- and double-precision data.

Comment: Thank you Steven. As i said, "i think i know" that. Do you find any documentation about that?

Comment: All of this is extensively documented in Intel's architecture reference manuals, which are a free download from their website.

Comment: That was my guess too - but i haven't found it.

Comment: It's not a guess.  The supported data types are extensively documented in sections 4.2.2, 8.2, 10.3, and 11.3 of Volume 1 of the Software Developer's Manual.  The fact that both x87 ("FPU") and SSE ("XMM") are supported on all recent Intel architectures is documented in section 2.3.